# Permission Denial: starting Intent sharing with gmail

Tags: android

I tried to share some text with gmail in my app :

```
String shareBody = "bla bla bla";
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
sharingIntent.setType("plain/text");
sharingIntent.setClassName("com.google.android.gm", "com.google.android.gm.ComposeActivityGmail");
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "bla bla bla");
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
startActivity(sharingIntent);
```

But I have the error message when I click on the share button :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
     Process: opteamit.com.belami, PID: 14263
     java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW typ=plain/text cmp=com.google.android.gm/.ComposeActivityGmail (has extras) } from ProcessRecord{f3970e9 14263:opteamit.com.belami/u0a170} (pid=14263, uid=10170) not exported from uid 10085
         at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1620)
         at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1573)
         at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:3131)
         at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1541)
         at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4298)
         at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4245)
         at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4582)
         at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4550)
         at opteamit.com.belami.AideActivity$4$1.onSuccess(AideActivity.java:89)
         at com.loopj.android.http.JsonHttpResponseHandler$1$1.run(JsonHttpResponseHandler.java:152)
         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

What can I do ?

Answer (score 3):

> What can I do ?

Get rid of the `setClassName()` call.

First, that activity is not exported, so you cannot invoke it directly.

Second, that activity may not exist in past, present, and future editions of Gmail.

Third, not every Android user uses Gmail. [Share where the *user* wants](https://commonsware.com/blog/2011/06/28/share-where-the-user-wants.html).