# "java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent" sending an email on Android

Tags: android, email, android-intent, gmail

I have an `alertDialogBuilder` that creates an Intent to send an email.

It worked well but since last week it stopped to work and is giving the following error:

> java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent

I am using the same device all the time with Android versión 4.4.2 and on my gradle I am supporting the following versions:

```
minSdkVersion 16
targetSdkVersion 23
```

My code is:

```
alertDialogBuilder
    .setMessage("Do you want to send an email to " + getString(R.string.companyName) + "?")
    .setCancelable(false)
    .setPositiveButton("Send",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {

                Intent gmail = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                gmail.setClassName("com.google.android.gm","com.google.android.gm.ComposeActivityGmail");
                gmail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { "myEmail@email.com" });
                gmail.setData(Uri.parse("myEmail@email.com"));
                gmail.setType("plain/text");
                startActivity(gmail);
          }
    })
    .setNegativeButton("Cancel",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   dialog.cancel();
            }
    });
```

I know that there are two questions directly related with this question:

- [Permission Denial: starting Intent sharing with gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40871477/permission-denial-starting-intent-sharing-with-gmail)
- [Send email through Intent : SecurityException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40627368/send-email-through-intent-securityexception)

but I could not solve my problem with none of them. I also does not understand why it worked one week ago and now it stopped to work. I did not make any changes on Gmail application on my device and I have it installed on the device too.

What am I missing? I can paste the full stacktrace if required, I have put only the error name to reduce the size of the question.

**EDIT:** My error stacktrace is the following:

```
12-27 17:38:15.507 7816-7816/com.project.user.product E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
         Process: com.project.user.product, PID: 7816
         java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.SEND typ=plain/text cmp=com.google.android.gm/.ComposeActivityGmail (has extras) } from ProcessRecord{428b7c68 7816:com.project.user.product/u0a107} (pid=7816, uid=10107) not exported from uid 10048
             at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1472)
             at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1426)
             at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:2222)
             at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1425)
             at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3480)
             at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3432)
             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:842)
             at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3683)
             at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3651)
             at com.project.user.product.LoginActivity$7$2.onClick(LoginActivity.java:284)
             at android.support.v7.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:157)
             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333)
             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:828)
             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:644)
             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "I can paste the full stacktrace if required" -- that is probably a good idea. A better idea is to get rid of `gmail.setClassName("com.google.android.gm","com.google.android.gm.ComposeActivityGmail");`, as AFAIK that activity is no longer exported (which would lead to your error message), and it was a user-hostile idea in the first place.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you for answer but I do not really understand what do you mean with the second part of your comment. And instead of that function what should I use? Or just rid it?

Comment: "I do not really understand what do you mean with the second part of your comment" -- not everybody uses Gmail. Your code assumes that everybody does. For non-Gmail users, your app may crash (Gmail does not exist) or route users into a Gmail onboarding that they do not want. "Or just rid it?" -- correct.

Comment: @CommonsWare So, how should I configure it? Or just rid that line? I have updated the question with the error stacktrace. In the device that I am using now I have installed Gmail.

Comment: @CommonsWare Ok. Thank you! It worked so good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
gmail.setClassName("com.google.android.gm","com.google.andro‌​id.gm.ComposeActivit‌​yGmail");
```

This statement says that your app *requires* that the user use Gmail, and more specifically, that the user use some older version of Gmail. Hence, your code does not support:

- Users of devices where Gmail simply is not installed (which may or may not be a possibility, depending upon your app distribution channels)
- Users of devices where they do not have access to Gmail (e.g., secondary device users)
- Users of devices where they have Gmail disabled, because they use some other email account (e.g., me)
- Users of devices where they have Gmail available, but do not normally use it or would prefer not to use it for this particular situation
- Users of devices with a current version of Gmail, as `com.google.andro‌​id.gm.ComposeActivit‌​yGmail` is no longer available for direct launch by third-party apps, such as yours

The latter point is what is leading to your exception.

So, delete that statement. Also:

- `plain/text` is not a valid MIME type. Use `text/plain`. Or, better yet, get rid of `gmail.setType("plain/text");` entirely, as you are not using `EXTRA_TEXT` or `EXTRA_STREAM`, and that is what the MIME type of an `ACTION_SEND` `Intent` is tied to.
- Delete `gmail.setData(Uri.parse("myEmail@email.com"));`, as `ACTION_SEND` does not use the data facet of the `Intent`.

Comment: Thank you very much! Nice explanation. Nevertheless, it does not give me any problem using `plain/text`. Is just a coincidence?

Comment: @Error404: The apps that are responding to your `Intent` probably have a MIME type filter of `*/*`. Any that had `text/plain` or `text/*` would not show up as an option for you.

Comment: I have tried removing the line `gmail.setType("plain/text")` and it gives to me the following error: `android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent`. If I use `text/plain` instead I get more applications to choose between than when I was using `plain/text`.

Comment: @Error404: Usually, when developers use `ACTION_SEND`, it is with the intent to actually send something, and the MIME type is the type of the "something". In your case, you are not sending anything (no `EXTRA_TEXT` and no `EXTRA_STREAM`). I had not thought that all the way through, and you are going to need some MIME type, even if it is superfluous. "If I use text/plain instead I get more applications to choose between than when I was using plain/text." -- from the user's standpoint, this is generally a good thing.

Comment: Ok, now I understand it. Thank you very much for your help. As usually, you saved my day :)

Answer (score 2):

**Updated 2020 answer:**

Instead of `setClassName`, use `setPackage("com.google.android.gm")`

Comment: Thanks, confirming it works in 2024 as well.